Have HDMI electromagnetic radiation privacy attacks already been used against government agencies and sensitive industrial settings?
I read on AI can see what's on your screen by reading HDMI electromagnetic radiation regarding sneaking on someone's screen by reading HDMI electromagnetic radiation:

The researchers say these attacks are already being used against government agencies and sensitive industrial settings.

No evidence or details were given.
Have there been any documented such cases?

The article also say "their AI-powered cable-tapping method is good enough that these attacks are likely already happening". It seems to be speculation, especially as they also say their method is 70% correct, and 60% better than previous attempts.

Does the article say what the AI has to do with it? To me the AI in front makes this claim less credible than if they had written 'statistical analysis' or whatever it is they are actually doing.

@quarague trained a neural network.

The article doesn't say where the magnetic field is tapped. HDMI cables are shielded pretty well and the residual radiation decays quite quickly with distance. If this attack requires putting a clamp on the HDNI cable (as is done for current measurements), it may not be as dangerous as they make it out to be.

@quarague There’s still the non-LLM AIs around. To do this kind of thing one would train an AI in an instrumented environment, where in addition to the HDMI signal one also has access to the "true" picture. Automated statistical analysis is exactly what AI was in recent years and to most researchers still is.

Sounds like Van Eck phreaking with an AI, because everything nowadays needs more AI. Wouldn't be surprised if such technology was used against government agencies and for industrial espionage. But as you correctly mentioned, there is no evidence given.

Could this "new technology" possibly be just TempestSDR with AI upscaling?

@tpimh The article explains that capturing analogue signals has been widely demonstrated, but claims that digital signals are harder to interpret. So the novel invention is using a machine learning algorithm to recognise patterns in the noise from a digital signal which correspond to known images.

This article from 2019 gives some more details on the phenomenon (no mention of AI, though). I'm not smart enough to summarize it for a formal answer.

Is the question specifically about HDMI or is it the more general claim that with the right equipment one could “see” what is displayed on a remote computer screen? If the latter, that was already true in the 1990s, we were taught about it in (entry-level) communications security training in the French Army back then.

Go with JCaron, please.
Cables leak information and when snoopers will be able to read that leaked information seems largely a matter of waiting enough time for technology to catch up.
When TV first appeared, who knew detector teams would be able to see anything, or spy teams would be able to see what signals went in or out of embassies, but did they?
AI comes into this because broadly, AI is much better able than we mere humans to detect patterns, meaning much less electronics is needed for the snoops to read the signals.
